# Removing or hiding WooCommerce add to cart buttons

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I would like to hide add to cart button and to show a custom text instead of button.

I am trying following hook to remove button:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');

remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart');
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the way that you are looking for *(I think)*.

The first function will replace on shop pages the add-to-cart buttons by normal buttons linked to their single product pages, like below:

[image]

The second function will replace the add-to-cart button (and quantities) by your custom text as this:

[image]

Here is that code:

```
// Shop and archives pages: we replace the button add to cart by a link to the product
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'custom_text_replace_button', 10, 2 );
function custom_text_replace_button( $button, $product  ) {
    $button_text = __("View product", "woocommerce");
    return '<a class="button" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a>';
}

// replacing add to cart button and quantities by a custom text
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'replacing_template_single_add_to_cart', 1, 0 );
function replacing_template_single_add_to_cart() {

    // Removing add to cart button and quantities
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );

    // The text replacement
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', function(){

        // set below your custom text
        $text = __("My custom text goes here", "woocommerce");

        // Temporary style CSS
        $style_css = 'style="border: solid 1px red; padding: 0 6px; text-align: center;"';

        // Output your custom text
        echo '<p class="custom-text" '.$style_css.'>'.$text.'</a>';
    }, 30 );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works

Answer (score 0):

**1**. In case you want to completely disable Add to cart button, add this code to your theme's functions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', false );
```

**2**. To add some HTML content after Add to cart button, try this code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'add_content_after_addtocart_button_func' );

function add_content_after_addtocart_button_func() {
    echo '<p>Hi, I'm the text after Add to cart Button.</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with a Wordpress plugin, i found later https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-options/